# Access a remote MySQL DB when developing locally

Tags: php, mysql, mamp

I'm developing locally with MAMP. Now that my site is live, I still want to develop locally, but be able to interact with the production MySQL DB.

How can I have my local site access my MySQL DB on my server? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to develop against a production server?  Sounds like madness to me.

Just changing the connection URL and credentials should do it, but I don't advise that you do so.  I'd prefer a development server, separate from production.

Answer (score 1):

yes ... its is possible

you need to create a remote mysql user

```
mysql> CREATE USER 'myuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
mysql> GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'myuser'@'%';
```

then on your php code:

```
mysql_connect("your server hostname","username","password");
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the PDO API to create a database connection (probably in some include file), you would just point that at your production database. But as a general rule, you shouldn't be developing on your production server as you could potentially lose production data. Consider why you want to do this and whether it is necessary.